# Docker launch makes several WSL distributions to comeup

Tags: docker, wsl-2

Docker desktop is not running, 'wsl -l -v' shows:

[image]

Launch docker desktop, now 'wsl -l -v' shows:

[image]

Quit docker desktop, 'wsl -l -v' shows:

[image]

Ubuntu is one I configured when I installed wsl. Other 2 are coming from docker installation, going by the name, not sure why 2 though.

So which one is being used by docker actually? All three come up when docker is running, and all three are stopped otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Desktop uses *at least* two WSL2 distributions, but usually uses three, as in your case:

- `docker-desktop` is used internally by Docker Desktop.  It contains a BusyBox/musl-based distribution where the Docker CLI tools and Docker Engine run.  It *can* be launched by an end-user, but it is not intended to be used directory.  Changes made to this distribution will usually be overwritten when updating Docker Desktop.
- `docker-desktop-data` is where the images and volumes are stored.  This distribution does not contain a shell, and thus is not launchable by an end user in WSL2, at least not in any usable fashion.  Docker Desktop "launches" this distribution, AFAICT, with something along the lines of `wsl -d docker-desktop-data -e /wsl-keepalive`, which just makes sure the distribution is available while Docker Desktop is running.
- Finally, Docker Desktop "injects" the Docker CLI commands and sockets into any "user" distribution that you are using, *assuming* you have it configured in the *Docker Desktop Settings* -> *Resources* -> *WSL Integration*.  Any distribution selected here will be automatically started with Docker Desktop so that the symlinks and mounts can be properly injected.

It's entirely possible to turn off this integration, in which case Docker commands would still be available from PowerShell and CMD, but not from Ubuntu.

For a more in-depth look at the architecture, see [my Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1778525/1210833) on the topic.